# Receiving specific AD ldap error when trying to do a username lookup

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2016

I am trying to do a username lookup onto my active directory and even when I am using the proper credentials I am still getting this error. I even verified I was able to connect to the ldap but I just can't authenticate to do a lookup.

> [LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042A, comment:
>   AcceptSecurityContext error, data 2030, v3839]; nested exception is
>   javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C:
>   LdapErr: DSID-0C09042A, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data
>   2030, v3839]

Even tried creating a new user account and that still wont authenticate with it as well.

Comment: Did you find an explaination for this error, and did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

First off, [show how you are doing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) the bind. (like the code)

Are you sure you have proper permissions?

Generally the respsonse breaks down like: (From what I have discovered)

LDAP: error code 49 - is the standard [LDAP Result Code](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20Result%20Codes)

data 2030 - Usually (when error code 49) this is is an [server provided Client Bind Error](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors) However I have not seen 2030 in my travels.

Regardless the credentials provided are invalid or some account restriction is preventing a bind to complete.

I would recommend you perform the LDAP bind with some "Known" application. (I like Apache Studio)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction on where I could start on finding how too resolve this issue. I actually did use apache studio to test and i received the same error